# Signal Handling Functionalities in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: c, unix, signals, ubuntu-11.04

I have tried to write a signal handling functions in ubuntu. The code is the following:

```
   #include<signal.h>
   void abc();

   main(){

   printf("Press Ctrl-z key to send SIGINT signal");
   signal(SIGINT,abc);
   for(;;);
   }
   void abc(){
   printf("The key has been pressed");
   }
```

The intersting factor is:
a) First printf() is not shown
b) As well as the second printf();

I wrote the code from a book. Can any one pls tell me what mistakes i have made or whether the code will be alterd for ubuntu.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdout` is line buffered.

You might like to append a `\n` to the strings passed to `printf()`:

```
printf("The key has been pressed.\n");
```

---

If `Crtl-C` is pressed `SIGINT` is sent to the process running in foreground. The default handler for `SIGINT` ends the app.

As the OP's app installs a signal handler for `SIGINT` which does not end the app, it continues to run if `Ctrl-C` is pressed and therefore a `SIGINT` is raised. It is called on `Ctl-C` as long as it stays installed.

To achieve the behaviour of having `abc()` called only once, modify the signal handler as follows:

```
void abc(int sig) /* 'sig' gets the signal nuber passed in (here: 'SIGINT') */
{
  printf("The key has been pressed.\n");
  signal(sig, SIG_DFT); /* (re-)sets the signal handler for `sig` to the default handler. */
}
```

---

Further readings: `man signal`, `man sigaction`

Comment: thank you very much. But your answer and my output of the program raises few question: Can you pls answer it:                                                                   a) what is the logic behind putting \n to execute the signal functions i have made?                                                                b) My output continue to show DEL IS PRESSED as long as a press ctrl-c. It terminates aftr i press ctrl-z. But my logic says that "DEL is pressed" will show for once and aftr if i press ctl-c it will terminate. Can u pls explain the logic behind? Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @user2015915 Sounds like you've been messing with `stty`... "Usually", `SIGINT`, corresponds to `ctrl-c`, not `ctrl-z` (which usually means `SIGTSTP`), and `DEL` is not related to a signal. It's not real clear here what exactly you're trying to do...

Comment: @twalberg: Sry.I have written this code from a book based upon UNIX where they use signal DEL.I didnt get that whether its ctrl-c ot ctrl-z. But its ctrl-c because if u press ctrl-z the abc() has not executed My output will be, aftr pressing ctrl-c it will show the 2nd printf() rather terminatng the process. The theory says that if u press ctrl-c for the scnd time it will terminate. But in my case, the scnd printf() executes as long as u press ctrl-c